# How to disable http method verb tunneling in nginx

Tags: nginx, http-headers

Our security team ran a web-inspect security scan on our site and asked us to disable verb tunneling using  headers or query parameters such as `X-HTTP-Method`, `XHTTP-Method-Override`, `X-Method-Override`, or a query parameter such as `_method` to prevent attackers from using an override method to use restricted HTTP methods. Is there a way in nginx configurations where we can disable this verb tunneling ?

Comment: Is your nginx server reverse proxying the content?  If so, you can override headers during the proxy process as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44536548/how-to-remove-client-headers-in-nginx-before-passing-request-to-upstream-server

Comment: I think it is likely your web application that supports these action overrides rather than nginx itself.   What web-app are you using?

Comment: Thanks for responding @StephenOstermiller . Will look into modifying headers while reverse proxying the content. Our upstream servers are with `fastcgi_pass`  (php-fpm servers). Web application is Drupal 7.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're getting the issue "Often Misused: HTTP Method Override" reported by Fortify's WebInspect scanner. To resolve this for my team I implemented a filter in the WebApp itself that listens for our bad headers (x-http-method, x-http-method-override, x-method-override), sets status to 405, and breaks if they are found. See code below. I know this is not the most graceful solution, but it is the only one I found that satisfies the scan (throwing an error and booting the user did not satisfy).

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest hsReq = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse hsRes = (HttpServletResponse) res;

    hsRes.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
    hsRes.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    hsRes.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
    hsRes.setHeader("X-XSS-Protection", "1; mode=block");
    hsRes.addHeader("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
    hsRes.setHeader("Content-Security-Policy", "frame-ancestors 'none'; default-src *; style-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'");
    hsRes.setHeader("X-FRAME-OPTIONS", "DENY");
    hsRes.setHeader("Strict-Transport-Security", "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains;");

    // This resolves "Often Misused: HTTP Method Override"
    hsRes.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
    String methodParam = hsReq.getParameter("_method");
    if (methodParam != null){
        LOG.error("\n Bad actor is attempting to use HTTP Method Tunneling. \n");
        hsRes.reset();
        hsRes.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED);
        return;
    }
    String xhmHeader = hsReq.getHeader("x-http-method");
    String xhmoHeader = hsReq.getHeader("x-http-method-override");
    String xmoHeader = hsReq.getHeader("x-method-override");
    if ((xhmHeader != null) || (xhmoHeader != null) || (xmoHeader != null)){
        LOG.error("\n Bad actor is attempting to use HTTP Method Tunneling. \n");
        hsRes.reset();
        hsRes.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED);
        return;
    }

    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}
```